# extract http:// URL from file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to extract `http://` URL from given file but getting empty file in export

Here is the code:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "E:\Backup_Testinstance\" |
         Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq "http://"}

$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($item in $items)
{
  foreach ($item in $items) {
    $array.Add([pscustomobject]@{
        "Name File" = $item.name
        "Path" = $item.FullName
    }) | Out-Null
}

$array | Export-csv E:\Backup_Testinstance\test2.csv
```

Here is the source file records:

```
sdfadsfdsafadsf http://google.com/search/fddggddfadfdsfdfdfadsfgdadsfdsfdsfd  99999999
sdfadsfdsafadsf http://van.com/search/fddggddfadfdsfdfdfdsfgdadsfdsfdsfd  99999999
sdfadsfdsafadsf http://gem.com/search/fddggddfadfdsfdfadsfgdadsfdsfdsfd  99999999
sdfadsfdsafadsf http://cart.com/search/fddggdfdsfdfdfadsfgdadsfdsfdsfd  99999999
```

Comment: I (deliberately) removed the spaces between `http://` and the hostname in your source file sample, please review that it's correct

Comment: Are you sure that you have files with an extension of `http://`?

Comment: Are you sure that your nested foreach loops should use the same variable?

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path C:\check\two -recurse |  Select-String -Pattern "http://" | `  Select-Object -Property Path,LineNumber,Line | `    Export-CSV "C:\check\ResultFile.csv"   i tried this query and works but do not want data after space\

Comment: yes  is shown the test data

Comment: yes u want to add  all http sites

Comment: unable to get data from multiple folders and files using above command             Get-ChildItem -Path C:\check\two -recurse | Select-String -Pattern "http://" | ` Select-Object -Property Path,LineNumber,Line | ` Export-CSV "C:\check\ResultFile.csv"

Answer (score 0):

The code in your latest comment looks fine, except for the backticks, the missing `-Filter '*.txt'` (or whatever the extension of the files is), the missing `-File` switch and the missing `-NoTypeInformation` switch on the `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

Try writing this in separate code lines:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\check\two' -Filter '*.txt' -File -Recurse | 
Select-String -Pattern "http://" | 
Select-Object -Property Path,LineNumber,Line | 
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\check\ResultFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

For me this works